# Retrieving <img>s from nested divs

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the urls of images from pinterest, I've tried the below code, but getElementsByTagName is retuning null.

The img elements are inside of many nested divs. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, please help!!

```
$html = file_get_html("https://www.pinterest.ca/search/pins/?q=cakes");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
echo $images->length;
foreach($images as $image){
  echo $image->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, might be it will help you.

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.pinterest.ca/search/pins/?q=cakes");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
echo $images->length;
foreach($images as $image){
    if(isset($image)) {
        echo $image->getAttribute('src');        
    }
}
```